# Every finite dimensional subspace $V\subset W$ of a inner product space $W$ is closed.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I'm reading this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.0952v2.pdf) (pag. 31), but I don't understand a part of it. Lemma 3.1 states

> Lemma 3.1. Every finite dimensional subspace $V\subset W$ of a inner product space W is closed.

In the proof one takes a sequence $v_{i}\in V$ that converges to $w\in W$, and take an orthonormal basis $u_{1},...,u_{r}$ of $V$. Let $\tilde{w}=w-\langle w,u_{1}\rangle u_{1}-...-\langle w,u_{r}\rangle u_{r}$. Here $w-\tilde{w}$ is the projection of $w$ onto $V$.

Then say by Pythagoras' theorem, $\|\tilde{w}\|\leq\|w-v_{i}\|$, I don't understand this part, why is that?
Any help to proof, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note** $\tilde{w}$ is perpendicular on $V$. You also have $w-\tilde{w} \in V$ and hence $w-\tilde{w}-v_i \in V$.

This showw that $\tilde{w} \perp w-\tilde{w}-v_i$. By the Pytagoras Theorem

$$\| \tilde{w} \|^2 + \|  w-\tilde{w}-v_i \|^2 = \|  w-\tilde{w}-v_i+\tilde{w} \|^2 = \|w-v_{i}\|^2$$

and hence
$$\| \tilde{w} \|^2 \leq  \|w-v_{i}\|^2$$

Answer (score 2):

$\tilde w$ is the projection of $w$ onto the orthogonal complement of $V$. The idea is to prove that $\tilde w=0$. Otherwise, you would have $\|v_i-w\|\ge \|\tilde w\|>0$, contradicting the convergence $v_i\to w$. The reason why $\|v_i-w\|\ge \|\tilde w\|$ is that $\|\tilde w\|$ is the minimum distance from $w$ to $V$. The distance between any $v\in V$ and $w$ is greater than or equal to $\|\tilde w\|$. This follows from Pythagorean theorem applied to the projections onto $V$ and $V^\perp$. For any vector in $W$, you have $\|P_V(w)\|^2+\|P_{V^\perp}(w)\|^2=\|w\|^2$.

Answer (score 1):

You have $\|v_i-w\|^2 = \|\tilde{w}\|^2 + \|\tilde{w}-w-v_i\|^2 \ge \|\tilde{w}\|^2$.

Since $v_i \to w$, we see that $\tilde{w}=0$.